# React Component (audio player) working in Firefox browsers but not in Chrome browsers

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, material-ui, html5-audio

I have an audio player component in a NextJs project with MaterialUI. Part of it is a MUI Slider component used to represent the progress of the audio playback. As the audio plays, the timeProgress state is updated, and the Slider component reflects this change by moving its thumb along the track.

This audio player is working perfectly fine in Firefox. However, in Chrome the progress bar does not update/move when the audio file is playing.

Does anyone know what is causing this issue in Chrome, and how it can be resolved?

AudioPlayer.js

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Controls from './Controls';
import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar';

const AudioPlayer = ({ track }) => {
    const [timeProgress, setTimeProgress] = useState(0);
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
    const audioRef = useRef();
    const progressBarRef = useRef();

    const onLoadedMetadata = () => {
        const seconds = audioRef.current.duration;
        setDuration(seconds);
        progressBarRef.current.max = seconds;
    };

    return (
        <Grid container spacing={0.5} alignItems="center">
            <audio src={track} ref={audioRef} onLoadedMetadata={onLoadedMetadata} />
            <Grid item xs={2}>
                <Controls
                    {...{
                        audioRef,
                        progressBarRef,
                        setTimeProgress,
                    }}
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={8} sx={{ marginLeft: 1 }}>
                <ProgressBar
                    {...{ progressBarRef, audioRef, timeProgress, duration }}
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
};

export default AudioPlayer;
```

Controls.js

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Slider from '@mui/material/Slider';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import PopupState, { bindPopover, bindHover } from 'material-ui-popup-state';
import HoverPopover from "material-ui-popup-state/HoverPopover";
import { PlayerArrow, PlayerPause, PlayerMute, PlayerVolHigh, PlayerVolLow } from '../../utils/CommonIcons';

const Controls = ({ audioRef, progressBarRef, setTimeProgress, }) => {
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [volume, setVolume] = useState(60);
    const [muteVolume, setMuteVolume] = useState(false);

    const togglePlayPause = () => {
        setIsPlaying((prev) => !prev);
    };

    const playAnimationRef = useRef();

    const repeat = useCallback(() => {
        if (audioRef && audioRef.current) {
            const currentTime = audioRef.current.currentTime;
            setTimeProgress(currentTime);
            progressBarRef.current.value = currentTime;

            playAnimationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(repeat);
        }
    }, [audioRef, progressBarRef, setTimeProgress]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isPlaying && audioRef && audioRef.current) {
            audioRef.current.play();
        } else if (audioRef && audioRef.current) {
            audioRef.current.pause();
        }
        playAnimationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(repeat);

        return () => {
            cancelAnimationFrame(playAnimationRef.current);
        };
    }, [isPlaying, audioRef, repeat]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (audioRef) {
            audioRef.current.volume = volume / 100;
            audioRef.current.muted = muteVolume;
        }
    }, [volume, audioRef, muteVolume]);

    return (
        <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center">
            <IconButton onClick={togglePlayPause}>
                {isPlaying ? <PlayerPause fontSize='small' /> : <PlayerArrow fontSize='small' />}
            </IconButton>
            <PopupState variant="popover" popupId="volume-hover-popover">
            .
            .
            .
            </PopupState>
        </Stack>
    );
};

export default Controls;
```

ProgressBar.js

```
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Slider from '@mui/material/Slider';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

const ProgressBar = ({
    progressBarRef,
    audioRef,
    timeProgress,
    duration,
}) => {

    const handleProgressChange = (event, newValue) => {
        audioRef.current.currentTime = newValue;
    };

    const formatTime = (time) => {
        if (time && !isNaN(time)) {
            const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
            const formatMinutes =
                minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : `${minutes}`;
            const seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
            const formatSeconds =
                seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : `${seconds}`;
            return `${formatMinutes}:${formatSeconds}`;
        }
        return '00:00';
    };

    return (
        <Stack spacing={2} direction="row" alignItems="center">
            <Box sx={{ fontSize: 13, width: '50px', textAlign: 'right' }}>
                {formatTime(timeProgress)}
            </Box>
            <Slider
                ref={progressBarRef}
                value={timeProgress}
                max={duration}
                onChange={handleProgressChange}
            />
            <Box sx={{ fontSize: 13, width: '50px', textAlign: 'left' }}>
                {formatTime(duration)}
            </Box>
        </Stack>
    );
};

export default ProgressBar;
```

Some findings when using Chrome browser:

- There are no warning/error logs in browser console log.
- Audio current time (timeProgress) is updated correctly as the audio file is playing.
- Progress bar thumb moves to the end when the audio playback ends.
- Progress bar thumb sometimes move correctly with the current playtime when the mouse cursor moves out of the browser window.

The tested browser versions are:

```
    Chrome Version 119.0.6045.159 (Official Build) (64-bit)
    Firefox 120.0 (64-bit)
```

Comment: I found that using the html input element instead of the MUI Slider component as the progress bar works. However, I wish to know what is the issue causing the MUI slider not to work correctly in Chrome browsers. And what are the possible solutions to fix this MUI Slider issue in Chrome.